# array contains values of sample wav file in python or matlab

Tags: python, matlab, wav

I'm new at python and matlab, I tried to program using both language I couldn't get the right result. 
I want take a wav file as input and give an array which contains values of samples of the audio signal as output according to the sampling frequency. and the values are all between 0-255 for 8bit output.

Comment: see help: `y = wavread(filename) loads a WAVE file specified by the string filename, returning the sampled data in y`